# How do I store varying length lists/orders in database?

Tags: mysql, json

I have been working on a project where I need to store lists of orders (Food in this case) in a database.

I have tried looking around for the best way of storing these sort of lists, but I wasn't able to find any method of doing it.

At the moment, I am storing the data in phpMyAdmin/SQL with the orders being stored as raw HTML to be printed. It works, but there must be a more efficient way to store these orders.

The orders look similar to this:

1. Burger Meal

   - Chips
   - Water
2. Chicken Parma

   - Lemonade

So, what I thought would be good is to make a separate table to hold the orders so that it is structured a bit better but I can't figure out a viable way to deal with the varying lengths of orders. Otherwise, would be it be better to store it as JSON or an array and construct it in JS?

JSON example:

```
{
 "order_id": 666,
 "orders": [{
             "item": "Burger Meal",
             "notes": ["Chips", "Water"]
            },
            {
             "item": "Chicken Parma",
             "notes": ["Lemonade"] //<-- Simpler to detect number of notes?
            }]
}
```

**TL;DR:** Best way to store varying length list in database?

Comment: Store them in tables. This is what database design is all about. Orders are usually stored in 2 tables: a header and a detail. Each order has a single record in the header table and a varying number of records in the detail table. The 2 tables are linked through the order id field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create an `order_items` table with a row for each item in each order, and an `item_notes` table with a row for each note.

```
CREATE TABLE order_items (
    item_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    order_id INT NOT NULL,
    quantity INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (item_id),
    UNIQUE KEY (order_id, name),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES orders(order_id)
);
CREATE TABLE item_notes (
    note_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    text VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    item_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (note_id),
    UNIQUE KEY (item_id, text),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES order_items(item_id)
);
```

You can then get all the information about an order with a join:

```
SELECT o.*, i.*, n.*
FROM orders AS o
LEFT JOIN order_items AS i ON o.order_id = i.order_id
LEFT JOIN item_notes AS n ON i.item_id = n.item_id
WHERE o.order_id = 666
```

Comment: Alright, just to clarify some details so I understand everything. _From my understanding_, order_items and item_notes are like a log/dump of all the item names and details, with these details being pulled with the query sent. _(aka, if I viewed these tables without parameters, it would look cluttered)_

I haven't really used "foreign keys" before, so I assume it's referencing the order table, so "where _this_tables_ order_id = orders order_id".

Finally, I see you have used `o.*, i.*, n.*` just wondering what the wildcards do here since I haven't seen this before.

Comment: `tablename.*` means to select all the columns from that table.

Comment: A foreign key means that all the values in `order_items.order_id` must match one of the values in `orders.order_id`. It doesn't make sense to have an item in a nonexistent order, and this enforces that relationship. You still have to write the relationship in the query explicitly.

Comment: Been playing around with this for a bit now, wondering how I would insert info, as I have been using phpmyadmin to add it thus far.

Comment: Use `INSERT INTO tablename` queries. First insert into `orders`, leaving out `order_id` so that it will be assigned by auto-increment. Assign `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to a variable, then use that variable when inserting into `order_items`. After inserting into `order_items`, use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` again to get `item_id` so you can include it in `item_notes`.

Comment: I know this question is from ages ago, but I am only getting around to implementing this now... :) woops. But I don't understand the use of `LAST_INSERT_ID()` since if I insert the first item, it will be fine, then the first not will be fine, but then won't the second note be referencing the last note id since it was the last input, then what happens with the next item input? since `LAST_INSERT_ID()` will now be the ID of the last note.

Comment: @sparcut That's why you need to assign `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to a variable, because the function keeps changing. `SET @order_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();`. Then use `@order_id` when you insert into `order_items`.

Comment: Yay, got it working after fiddling around with mutli_query() in PHP. Worked as you described cheers.

Comment: You don't need to use `multi_query()`. MySQL variables persist across all the queries using the same database connection.

Comment: Mostly it just seems to make the code more complicated, using a loop calling `next_result()` to get all the results.